# Rails 3 + Simple Form: Specifiy label class when using f.association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

How can I specify the label class when using `f.association` instead of `f.input` in simple_form?

For example, this works:

```
f.input :name, :label_html => { :class => 'some-class' }
```

But this doesn't

```
f.association :periods, :as => :check_boxes, :label_html => { :class => 'some-class' }
```

Meaning that the label related to `:name` will have some-class as part of its class, but the label related to `:periods` won't. Any way to do this without changing `f.association` to `f.input`? Thank!

Comment: Hey, what version of SimpleForm are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using simple_form 2.0.2

Comment: that's strange. It works on new app, I've just tested it. Could you show your simple_form.rb initializer?

Comment: not sure what you are expecting to see but label_html adds that custom class only to attribute's input not to every checkboxes.

Comment: You're right, nash, it adds that class to the attribute's input and not to every checkbox. I would like to add the class to all the checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't add custom class to each label but you can do it for each item wrapper, e.g:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :group, as: :check_boxes, item_wrapper_class: 'custom-class' %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This no longer works in the latest version and adds a custom class to another wrapper span :/ - any solution to changing the label class? :(

Comment: Hackeron Try with  input_html: { class: 'yourclass'}